# What is the preferred approach to express pure SHACL shape inheritance

Tags: rdfs, shacl

I have a quick question about the best way to express inheritance between pure SHACL shapes.

E.g.

```
:aShape a sh:nodeShape .
:bshape a sh:nodeShape .
```

Are the following 2 options equivalent, and which one is recommend?

```
bShape rdfs:subClassOf aShape;
```

or

```
bShape sh:node aShape ;
```

The goal is to have `bShape` inherit the property of `aShape`.

Comment: The SHACL user community is also on Discord and there was a discussion about inheritance on the #shacl-support channel:  (registration required) https://discord.com/channels/911006583067144212/911017258900398110/1101232770904244277

Comment: Can't find the channel, the link does not work for me. Could you give me the link to the channel please ?

Comment: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-shacl/2021Nov/0007.html